# Is there any alternative to cleanup function of useEffect?

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, lighthouse

I have a popup and I want that popup to be enabled for 3s. So I used setTimeout for 3s. Now I want to clear the timeout if the screeen is unmounted. But using this is giving me warning on lighthouse that unload is deprecated.

[Lighthouse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgezD.png)

Any alternative of cleanup function ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(popupTimeoutId);
    };
  }, []);
```

I am using cleanup function but needs a solution that can help me remove the lighthouse warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no React `useEffect` hook cleanup function alternative. The Lighthouse deprecation/warning has nothing to do with the `useEffect` hook though. It would seem that somewhere in your app you have instantiated a [`window.unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) event listener, which is a deprecated API.

[image]

There was also a deprecation warning from Chrome: [Deprecating the unload event](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/deprecating-unload).

I would suggest switching to the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event, though the above Chrome page suggests also trying/using [visibilitychange](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api#event-visibilitychange) and [pagehide](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api#event-pagehide) events as [Alternatives to unload events](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/deprecating-unload#alternatives_to_unload_events).

> Instead of unload it is recommended to use:
>
> - visibilitychange: To determine when the visibility of a page changes. This event happens when the user switches tabs, minimizes the
>   browser window, or opens a new page. Consider the hidden state the
>   last reliable time to save app and user data.
> - pagehide: To determine when the user has navigated away from the page. This event happens when the user navigates away from the page,
>   reloads the page, or closes the browser window. The pagehide event is
>   not fired when the page is simply minimized or switched to another
>   tab. Note that, as pagehide does not make a page ineligible for the
>   back/forward cache, it is possible a page can be restored after this
>   event fires. If you're cleaning up any resources in this event, then
>   they may have to be restored on page restore.
>
> The beforeunload event has a slightly different use case to unload in
> that it is a cancellable event. It is often used to warn users of
> unsaved changes when navigating away. This event is also unrealiable
> as it will not fire if a background tab is killed. It is recommended
> to limit use of beforeunload and only add it conditionally. Instead,
> use the above events for most unload replacements.

At the end of the day though, this is still *just a warning*, and you are free to ignore it with the understanding that your app/page may not function properly or as you expect in some browsers.